# How can I add a view after webview content ended in scroll view Swift?

Tags: swift, view, webview, webkit, scrollview

i'm trying to add a view just below my webview content. The webview content should be in full screen, then right after the content ended, I want to have a view there.

Here's what I created so far.

This is the storyboard

[image: storyboard]

This is the result when I started. as expected, long content and the button isn't shown but it's down there.

[image: 1]

Then after the content ended, the view shows as expected (even though it's not smooth like an integrated view and I have to swipe and bounce to show the view)

[image: content end]

then when I scroll up, the view should be down there. but it's not, it follows to the top of the screen.

[image: view followed]

Here's the code:

```
class BaseNotification: ViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonContainer: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollViewContainer: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonContainerTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonContainerHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var webViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var isUrlLoaded = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureWebView()
}

private func configureWebView() {
    webView.scrollView.delegate = self
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlArticle, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

I hope this make sense to you guys, thank you in advance

Comment: Width constraints are nor useful as you use leading and trailing. What happen is that you should have a constraint to set the height of the web view to the height of  view or safe area.